# Why does the IF condition is getting hit even the IF condition is not meeting?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have this code

the ordertype = 10

but still it goes into the first IF block but it shouldn't.

```
   OrderType_ID = ViewState("v_OrderTypeID")

    If OrderType_ID <> 7 & OrderType_ID <> 8 & OrderType_ID <> 9 & OrderType_ID <> 10 Then

        If OrderType_ID = 1 & OrderType_ID = 2 & OrderType_ID = 3 Then

            GenerateInvoiceNo_DebitCreditNote(False)   '' Credit note

        ElseIf OrderType_ID = 4 & OrderType_ID = 5 & OrderType_ID = 6 Then

            GenerateInvoiceNo_DebitCreditNote(True)   '' Debit note

        End If

    Else
        GenerateInvoiceAndDocNumber()
    End If
```

Comment: `&` is a bitwise operator. The boolean operator is `And` in vb

Comment: @Jamiec, in VB.NET, `&` is the string concatenation operator. `And` is a bitwise operator and a non-short-circuiting Boolean operator, while `AndAlso` is a short-circuiting Boolean operator. The direct equivalents in all four cases in C# are `+`, `&` and `&&`.

Comment: OP should first enable Option Strict, then he would see the problems earlier and with a meaningful error message. Otherwise you are in the magic conversion hell ;)

Comment: @jmcilhinney yep, of course. Its been a while since i wrote vb. For some reason thought `&` was bitwise like c#. Thanks for the clarification & good answer!

Comment: I second @TimSchmelter, **do not write a single line of code in VB without `Option Strict On` and `Option Explicit On`** you can set them project wide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the code as you have it, it should be like this:

```vb
OrderType_ID = ViewState("v_OrderTypeID")

If OrderType_ID <> 7 AndAlso
   OrderType_ID <> 8 AndAlso
   OrderType_ID <> 9 AndAlso
   OrderType_ID <> 10 Then
    If OrderType_ID = 1 OrElse
       OrderType_ID = 2 OrElse
       OrderType_ID = 3 Then
        GenerateInvoiceNo_DebitCreditNote(False)   '' Credit note
    ElseIf OrderType_ID = 4 OrElse
           OrderType_ID = 5 OrElse
           OrderType_ID = 6 Then
            GenerateInvoiceNo_DebitCreditNote(True)   '' Debit note
    End If
Else
    GenerateInvoiceAndDocNumber()
End If
```

Note that, not only were you not using an actual Boolean operator, you were also trying to use Boolean `AND` operators where you needed a Boolean `OR` operator. How could `OrderType_ID` be equal to 1, 2 and 3 all at the same time?

That said, there's a better way. The "proper" way to do this would be with a `Select Case` statement:

```vb
Select Case OrderType_ID
    Case 1 To 3
        GenerateInvoiceNo_DebitCreditNote(False)
    Case 4 To 6
        GenerateInvoiceNo_DebitCreditNote(True)
    Case 7 To 10
        GenerateInvoiceAndDocNumber()
End Select
```

If there's no way that `OrderType_ID` could be a value other than 1 to 10 or you want to do the same thing for other values too then you don't have to be explicit with the last case:

```vb
Select Case OrderType_ID
    Case 1 To 3
        GenerateInvoiceNo_DebitCreditNote(False)
    Case 4 To 6
        GenerateInvoiceNo_DebitCreditNote(True)
    Case Else
        GenerateInvoiceAndDocNumber()
End Select
```